# storing formatting in a python dictionary

Tags: python, django

Hopefully I'm not missing something obvious...

I'm creating a function that will ease in creating specifically formatted JSON data from a Django query. However, this should be a purely python question.

I'd like to be able to convert all values with a given index to a specified format with a function like the folowing:

```
data = [['foo1','bar1'],['foo2','bar2']]
format = {1:'VALUE says Hello world'}

>> some_function(data, format) 
[['foo1','bar1 says Hello World'],['foo2','bar2 says Hello World']]
```

Basic idea:

```
def some_function(data, format):
    for row in data:
        for count, value in enumerate(row):
            if format.has_key(count):
                #do something to replace 'VALUE' with value
            else:
                #just use value, no changes
    return formatted_data
```

The root of this question is that the data goes directly to web and I'd like to define specific formatting based on what I'm passing through the generic function.

Edit for clarity:

**What should I add to `some_function()` to convert the appropriate values in the data list to the format defined by the format dictionary?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def some_function(data, format):
    result = []
    for row in data:
        lst = []
        for count, value in enumerate(row):
            if count in format:
                string = format[count].format(value)
                lst.append(string)
            else:
                lst.append(value)
        result.append(lst)
    return result


data = [['foo1', 'bar1'], ['foo2', 'bar2']]
format = {1: '{0} says Hello world'}
print(some_function(data, format))
# prints: [['foo1', 'bar1 says Hello world'], ['foo2', 'bar2 says Hello world']]
```

The format you can use is explained in the [`docs`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: being the novice pythonista, i had to do a `type({0})` to realize that was a set. Seems cleaner and less dangerous/vulnerable to mistakes/conflicts than the % format method. Guess I have some doc reading and testing to do in the morning. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @j_syk, no it's not a set. It's just (part of) a string. The `.format` operation just treats that part of the string differently. I'll edit in a link to the `.format` documentation.

Comment: Outside of a string, curly brackets are used for sets and dicts, but inside a string, the {curly} brackets are a placeholder for a value that will be substituted in later!

Comment: @wim - good to know. any links to appropriate docs or articles would be cool. I like learning new python secrets, the zen about "one obvious way" isn't always easy!

Comment: @j_syk, link is in the answer now :)

Comment: @wim while I've personally used that site before... i'm still mad at you. I didn't quite know what to call it and who knows what "curly braces in python strings" would return.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest replacing format with `{1:'%s says Hello world'}`.
Then you can:

```
def some_function(data, format):
    formatted_data = []
    for row in data:
        r = []
        for count, value in enumerate(row):
            if count in format:
                value = format[count] % value

            r.append(value)

        formatted_data.append(r)

    return formatted_data
```

Though there are more elegant ways to do the task.

Comment: you know, I tried something similar to this, but what i was doing was trying to replace the str "VALUE" with %s and it was doing something funky when the escaping/substitution. I didn't consider to put pass %s directly... see the first 6 words of my post. Anyway, I'll try to implement this in the morning and see how it works. A quick test in shell looks good

Answer (score 1):

We want data that results from transforming each cell in each row, where the "transformation" is defined by looking up the cell's "column ID" (we can use `enumerate` to match up IDs to cell contents) in our "format" dictionary and applying the corresponding string formatter. When there isn't a format applied, we want to just use the original value; we can handle that by using a "default" format that has that result.

This is spelled:

```
def transform(data, formats):
    return [
        [
            formats.get(i, '{0}').format(column)
            for i, column in enumerate(row)
        ]
        for row in data
    ]

transform([['foo1','bar1'],['foo2','bar2']], {1:'{0} says Hello world'})
```

Comment: nice! but where I duped you is that my data is actually a list of objects (Django QuerySet) and I'm iterating over them and selectively using `getattr()` to create the `data` list of lists with the function I'm making. I had a feeling such a solution would appear as a result of my simplified example. However, this is a cool and clean solution for not rewriting unchanged data. Thanks Karl!

Comment: You should be able to apply the same sorts of techniques, though. It's really the same thing @RobWouters is doing but with a direct, functional-programming approach.